# Drag move grid not moving up

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am trying to drag a canvas around with a behavior and I have it working for horizontal movement but I cannot get it to work with vertical movement. When I try to drag it vertically it will jump up when I move the mouse up, and it will also jump up when I move the mouse down. It moves up in large increments. Horizontal movement works great though, and the code is the same idea.

The following is my behavior code.

```
 public class MouseDragPopupBehavior : Behavior<Grid>
{
    private bool _mouseDown;
    private Point _oldMousePosition;

    /// <summary>
    /// Called after the behavior is attached to an AssociatedObject.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Override this to hook up functionality to the AssociatedObject.
    /// </remarks>
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.MouseLeftButtonDown += (sender, e) =>
            {
                _mouseDown = true;
                _oldMousePosition = AssociatedObject.PointToScreen(e.GetPosition(AssociatedObject));
                AssociatedObject.CaptureMouse();
            };

        AssociatedObject.MouseMove += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (!_mouseDown) return;
                Point newMousePosition = AssociatedObject.PointToScreen(e.GetPosition(AssociatedObject));
                Vector offset = newMousePosition - _oldMousePosition;

                _oldMousePosition = newMousePosition;

                double horizontalMovement = Canvas.GetLeft(AssociatedObject) + offset.X;
                double verticalMovement = Canvas.GetTop(AssociatedObject) + offset.Y;

                // Works
                //double marginShift = AssociatedObject.Margin.Top + offset.Y;
                //AssociatedObject.Margin = new Thickness(0, marginShift, 0, 0);

                Canvas.SetLeft(AssociatedObject, horizontalMovement);

                // Does not work
                Canvas.SetTop(AssociatedObject, verticalMovement);
            };

        AssociatedObject.MouseLeftButtonUp += (sender, e) =>
            {
                _mouseDown = false;
                AssociatedObject.ReleaseMouseCapture();
            };
    }
}
```

My code works great for horizontal (left to right) movement, but not for vertical movement. I did get vertical movements to work by setting the margin as you can see by the commented out part, but I would really like to get it working the other way.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Seems like [MouseDragElementBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn195664.aspx) might save time & trouble instead of reinventing the wheel?

Comment: I am having trouble getting the MouseDragElementBehavior to work for me. It does allow me to drag the control around the screen, but when the control is hidden from view then shown again my previous code would place it at mouse click, but with this behavior it will place the control at mouse click + the difference from when the visibility was changed. That is why I was hoping to get my hack working.